# Cell Selector with phpexcel, issue grater than 20 items

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi to everyone I have an problem with `phpexel`, the problem is when I am creating a xls file, I want create a selector cell, so it works fine with 20 items but when it  become grater so the exel only return a value 0. My code is the follow:

```
    $blocksList = implode (", ", $unit);
      //Data Validation list
    $objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D1')->getDataValidation();

    $objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);

    $objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);

    $objValidation->setAllowBlank(true);

    $objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);

    $objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');

    $objValidation->setError('Value is not in list');

    $objValidation->setFormula1('"'.$blocksList.'"');
```

Any advice will be usefull to me,
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 255 character limit for a cell validation list in MS Excel, so it is possible that you are exceeding this limit, but you can always use a LOOKUP formula instead of a list in your validator

Comment: Thanks, do you have any example about this?

Comment: I have found this http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/80422 so I dont want to display in any cell information about the list, because my xls has already a format to use it.

Comment: You can't escape the 255 character limit: that's imposed by MS Excel, not by PHPExcel. If you don't want users to see a list of cell values used for a LOOKUP() formula dropdown, then store them in a hidden worksheet.